# Is there any way to check .PEM file is Valid or not in iOS?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I have created production **AdHoc .pem** files. I have followed this steps:

By using [This Link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)
I created .PEM file and i checked does this valid or not by using following command like: 
**$php simplepush.php**

but i am getting an error like::

**Warning:** stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/mac-jarc/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 21

**Warning:** stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) in /Users/mac-jarc/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 21
Failed to connect: 0 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

But in my PHP developer said it's a .PEM file mistake . I tought it's not(Because i am very sure my .PEM file is perfect) and i suggested to him like it's a server ports issue

Can you please help me out regarding this:: How would i check does my .PEM file is valid or not.
Here is my php code:
[image]

Comment: 2195 port should be unblocked on your network .Cross Check it.

Comment: please make sure that a pem file you used its your local server or live server if you want to use it on live than change the url of sandbox this ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195  to gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Comment: ThanQ..  (Shall i check in my MiniMac) by using  $php simplepush.php  this command

Comment: using terminal, check whether  $php simplepush.php is showing any error or not. If its showing error, then try to create new .PEM file and try again.

Comment: also you can try with APN Tester application available in store.

Comment: Hi, (I recreated .PEM file also) and I downloaded that APN Tester Free app from App Store: i run the app but i am getting response like::      2016-01-06 06:40:21 +0000: Failed with sending data to gateway.push.apple.com:2195 with ERROR: -36, error code -36 
2016-01-06 06:40:21 +0000: Disconnected from server gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Comment: Hi, Now my ports are Open but still i am getting same error(What ever i mention on top). Can you plz help me out regarding this issue(Past 5 days onwards i am literally struggling this issue)